# Surrogate key in Spark batch or Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a usecase to generate a surrogate key (unique and increment by 1) for each record I am inserting into Hive table with Spark Streaming program. The key can never be repeated even the program restarts.

Based on my research this is not possible to implement in spark streaming as executors will run on different nodes.

Is there any way to implement this??

Comment: we can generate hashcode and make it unique, but it will not satisfy your "increment by 1" condition. Is that fine for you?..

Comment: I am fine with that. could you please let me know about generating hashcode on spark jobs and how do we make it unique.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Spark Batch

Use RDD.zipWithIndex() to set an index for each row.

> Spark Streaming

1. At the end of every batch, find the max key and store it into a persistent database.
2. At the beginning of every batch, get the max key of last batch and run the codes like this:

   val n = lastBatchMaxKey()
   df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(xx => {
       val (row, idx) = (xx._1, xx._2)
       val key = idx + n  // this is the key
   })

Comment: Does it produce unique value if the partitions are running on several nodes??

Comment: @AKC, yes, zipWithIndex means giving a unique index for each row in RDD.

Comment: Can i know the zipWithIndex equivalent in Java.

Comment: @AKC, JavaRDD.zipWithIndex()